# How can I have a Dynamic nested _Layout with razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, layout, dynamic, razor, nested

Is it possible to have dynamic nested _layout pages ?

Here's what I got:

_ShopDetailsLayout.cshtml (Dynamic nested _layout):

```
@model MVC.Web.Areas.Shop.Models.ShopDetailViewModel

@{ 
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; 
}
```

Credits.cshtml:

```
@model MVC.Web.Areas.Shop.Models.CreditsViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Credits";
    Layout = "~/Areas/Game/Views/Shared/_ShopDetailsLayout.cshtml";
}
```

the problem i am having is that the other pages, like Credits.cshtml is using the nested layout does not have the same @model so I get this error:

> The model item passed into the
>   dictionary is of type
>   'MVC.Web.Areas.Shop.Models.CreditsViewModel',
>   but this dictionary requires a model
>   item of type
>   'MVC.Web.Areas.Shop.Models.ShopDetailViewModel'.

I hope anyone can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your layouts to be compatible with the actual model.
You may want to use a common base type, or stick with the default `dynamic` model.